# The people can be seated around a circular table so that everyone is seated between two friends.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Suppose $n \ge 4$ people gathered for a dinner. Of those $n$ people any two of them together knows the remaining $n-2$. To show that the people can be seated around a circular table so that everyone is seated between two friends.

---

How I tried to approach the problem:

Consider the $n$ points as vertices of a graph $G$. There is an edge between two vertices if they know each other. By the condition that "any two of them together knows the remaining $n-2$," we have $$deg(u) + deg(v) = n-2.$$ My aim was to show that a Hamiltonian Circuit exists in the given graph so that I can define the sitting arrangement using the Hamiltonian Circuit.

But by $\textbf{Ore's theorem}$ we have:

If $deg(u) + deg(v) \ge n$ for every pair of distinct non-adjacent vertices $v$ and $w$ of $G$, then $G$ is Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The condition "any two of them together knows the remaining $n−2$" is much stronger than

$$deg(u) + deg(v) = n-2$$

in fact it implies that for any vertex $v$,

$$deg(v) \ge n-2$$

i.e. every person must know everyone else **except possibly one other person**

This is because if there were a person who didn't know two other people, then those two people would not know him, contradicting the given condition. Thus

$$
\begin{align}
deg(u) + deg(v) &\ge 2n-4 \\
\\
&\ge n
\end{align}$$

(the last step following since $n \ge 4$) and Ore's Theorem applies. Of course, as @Steven mentioned in a comment below, since $deg(v) \ge n-2$, Hamiltonicity can be more directly established by Dirac's Theorem.

Comment: With this kind of property you can directly show the conclusion by induction though.

Comment: Or with $deg(v)\geq n-2$ you can immediately apply Dirac's theorem to find hamiltonicity.

Comment: You're right, of course, I was just showing that the theorem the OP mentioned did apply as well.

Comment: @Aqua my reasoning was given right after my statement $deg(v) \ge n-2$. If there were a vertex $v$ with degree $< n-2$, then the person represented by $v$ would not know at least two other people. But then neither of those two people would know him, which contradicts the given condition.